# ViewPager control touch event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

> I have got viewpager. 
>   At the my  viewpagers first item i used lock pattern view (from google code)  my problem is when i try to use lockview my view pager start to swipe how can i fix my problem.
>   I tried lots of thing but I cant do it I hope anyone help me

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager" />
```

[image: problem visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your view:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
        pager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        pager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        break;
    }
}
```

`requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`:
Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events with onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent).